# In Service now, OAuth flow failed. Verify the configurations and try again. Error detail:invalid_request, Missing parameters: access_token

Tags: flask, oauth, servicenow

During Flask Oauth API  integration with Service Now, we are getting following error

Error!!! "OAuth flow failed. Verify the configurations and try again. Error detail:invalid_request, Missing parameters: access_token"
[image]
steps we followed:
system oAuth -> Application Registry-> Connect to a third-party OAuth Provider

for getting token we used the following parameters:
[image]

Note: Our Access Token URL will give only token and expiresin as a response in json format

please help us!!!